# How to Use WordPress as Static CMS Without Blog Posts

Tags: themes, cms

I am very new to **wordpress**. I want to edit a wordpress theme and remove the blogpost area from it so it can be converted into a website. I also want to make some other changes. 
How I am trying to do it is,

> " I viewed the HTML code of my page and
>   pasted in Dreamweaver and edited it.
>   Now I am stuck with how to upload it."

Please help me out. If there is a better way to do it please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats not really an ideal way to do it (and will bring all kinds of problems), what your real aim is, is to make [**wordpress into a CMS**](http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/wordpress-3-to-a-client-friendly-cms-in-7-easy-steps/) this way you can manage it as website from the wp-admin panel, add new pages etc, etc, the link i have added is just to give you an idea of whats involved, there are other Wordpress to CMS tutorials out there that will also help you.

Comment: I would also like to know that if I keep on adding pages like that everytime I want to upload then soon I will be out of tabs to display all of them. How do I solve that problem?

Comment: In wp-admin you can choose to attach pages to parent pages which will give you a dropdown menu to show your "new child" pages, (see the link above in my answer for how that works with the 2010 theme). this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Good_Navigation_Links details more about menus and how to use them in wp and also this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus take a day to sit down and read them and do some practicing, its all very easy, wordpress manages it all for you .... almost ....

Comment: Note: you don't actually *upload* content in WordPress; rather, you *store it in the database*. The only things that get uploaded are attached media, such as photos or audio files. As Martin explained, you can easily define Page hierarchy in WordPress, and any decent Theme will incorporate core Navigation Menu functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any of what you've done in order to use WordPress to manage static content. All you need to do:

1. Choose whatever Theme you want to use
2. Create your content as *static Pages*; don't bother with *Posts*
3. Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`, set the Front Page to display a static Page, and select whichever static Page you want to use as the Front Page

Now, your WordPress installation is set to display only static Pages, with no Blog Posts.